# CSS working with Chrome but not IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a list of CSS to format my link button but it appears only working in Chrome but not IE, any ideas, the hover and everything works just not the link itself

thanks in advance

CSS

```
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px; 
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  position: absolute; 
  margin-top: 0px; 
  margin-left: 400px;
  background-color: white; 
  color: white; 
  border: 4px solid #83b739;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #83b739;
  color: white;  
}
```

HTML

```
<button class="button button1"><a href="http://www.google.com">link</a></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not even a CSS issue, but rather an issue with nesting interactive elements like that.

Don't put a link inside a button. That's just bizarre. Use just the `<a>` element and style that.

Comment: could someone please give me an example on how to edit my code using a element?

Comment: Get rid of the button and  add the class to the link. `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="button button1">link</a>` should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what would have caused your problem, however is is most likely due to a css/html nesting problem, where multiple css styles interact with the nested elements differently on different browsers? It is better to simply remove the button element in the html and just style the `<a>` tag to look like a button. By doing this the code is less complicated, you should have fewer problems with styles and nested elements, and this is how most make link buttons anyway. Here is an example of how I made a link button in a recent project, some of the stylings are missing (custom fonts, etc) but it shows that you don't need the button tag, it works better without it, and how to make a button with just the `<a>` tag.

```css
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #1A75BB;
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
    background-color: #14598e;
    border-color: #14598e;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
    background-color: #1A75BB;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
    background-color: #14598e;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
  color: black;
    border-color: #14598e;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#section-one" class="btn btn-full">Why use AnyMath?</a>
<a href="#section-two" class="btn btn-ghost">What problems can AnyMath solve?</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not just about IE. Such link-inside-button does not work in Firefox too.

If you *really* (think twice) need this to be a *button* instead of just a link, remove the explicit link from your button and wrap the button in a [simple form](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2013/03/link-button/):

```html
<form action="http://example.com/">
    <button class="button button1" type="submit">link</button>
</form>
```

But based on your code, `button` element is unneeded, and you should just use a link instead:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/" class="button button1">link</button>
```

Comment: The `form` hack is a terrible idea! Yes it may work  but it is probably the worst possible way to do it. There is no need for a button tag just a well styled link.

Comment: @JonP You've probably forgot to add "imho". If someone really _needs_ a button, it should at least be implemented a way that works _consistently across browsers_. In other cases, regular links should be used of course (see the article available via the link I've provided for some details).